# vue.js synchronized play of video player components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple video player components on a page.
I need to implement a sync button on all of the componenets that what when pressed. sets the currentTime off all other "slave" videos to the same time as the "master" component, and plays/paused, rewinds etc.. all of the videos together.

Seems like the best approach is to communicate up to the parent, and have the parent synchronize all of the child components.

I could use some pointers on how to implement this in vue.

Comment: What Player? API?

Comment: html5 video tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you want to do this is create an event bus (just a data item that is, itself, a Vue instance) that you pass to each of the children as a [`prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props). When a sync button is pressed, the child will [`emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) an event on the bus. Each child will also [listen](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) for those events on the bus and set its video time accordingly.

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing. I did not pass it as prop, though.  Its globally available.